# How to make a recursive store procedure in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, recursion, recursive-query

I am currently working with MySQL database.
I have a table which it defines the employee role. The table schema can be seen below:

```
|-------------------|
| headidx | subsidx |
|-------------------|
|  90001  |  90002  |
|  90001  |  90003  |
|  90002  |  90004  |
|  90002  |  90005  |
|  90002  |  90006  |
|  90007  |  90008  |
|  90001  |  90010  |
|  90010  |  90011  |
|-------------------|
```

The head column is contains the head id, otherwise the subs column contains the sub id. If the head id is a "Diecrtor" so the subs will be a "manager" or "supervisor" then if the subs id a "Manager" so the subs id is "Staff". How can i get the member of subs id, if i just have the "director" id?

Ilustration: 
 
INPUT : 90001

Result : 90002,90003,90004,90005,90006,90010,90011

INPUT : 90002

 Result : 90004,90005,90006

INPUT : 90010

 Result : 90011

Please anyone help me how to fix this problem.

Comment: In MySQL this can't be done with a single SQL statement because - unlike nearly all other DBMS - it lacks the ability to do recursive queries. You will need to write a stored procedure to get that information.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : can you show me an example of store procedure that i've to use?

Answer (score 0):

You need this

```
SELECT subsidx 
FROM Table1
WHERE headidx >= 'YourValue'
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e7bdbb/5)

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT subsidx FROM YOUR_TABLE WHERE headidx >= SOME_VALUE
```